# WebClient return value from subscribe

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I try to validate captcha response using webclient non blocking method. So
its working but i need that my method return boolean value instead exception. How i can return value from subscribe?

```
        webClient
                .post()
                .uri(verifyUri)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(res -> res.bodyToMono(GoogleResponse.class))
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Request error"))
                .subscribe(GoogleResponse -> {
                    try {
                        log.debug("Google response: {}", GoogleResponse);
                        if (!GoogleResponse.isSuccess()) {
                            throw new ReCaptchaInvalidException("reCaptcha response is not valid");
                        }
                    } catch (ReCaptchaInvalidException e) {
                        throw new ReCaptchaUnavailableException("Registration unavailable at this time.  Please try again later.", e);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, are you writing a `Webflux` application or just using `WebClient` in a spring web application instead of `RestTemplate`.

If using `WebClient` in a regular Spring web application you can just call `Block()` for `WebClient` to fetch the data block the thread until the data has been received and then return the data for you.

If using `WebClient` in a `Webflux` application you should return the `Mono` or `Flux` all the way out to the calling client, since it is the calling client that is the subscriber. The client (say a react app, angular app or whatever) subscribes to your spring application. Your spring application in turn subscribes to something else and will then just relay the data to the original subscriber.

You havn't stated what kind of application you are writing and you have a vague bit of code, which in turn means that the answer is also vague.

Comment: i must use WebClient in my springboot app because resttemplate is deprecated soon

Comment: Actually a 'regular Spring Web application' also supports reactive return types, see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types (the penultimate row in the table).

Comment: i did not mention anywhere that it doesn't support reactive return types. i wrote you CAN... and you SHOULD....